# Any good sites explaining how to use PiTiVi?

Tags: video-editor, pitivi

I have played around with PiTiVi a bit, but I could still use some help.

Are there any good sites explaining how to use PiTiVi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you take a look at the [PiTiVi manual](http://www.pitivi.org/manual/) ?